# When is $xy \equiv x\pmod n, \exists x,y,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have two examples and need find conditions to be imposed for the given statement to always true.

The two examples are:

i) $x = 3, y=8, n= 7 => xy = 24 $

ii) $x = 2, y=10, n= 6 => xy = 20$

The two examples differ in $n$ being prime in one, and composite in another. Still it holds true.

Comment: You probably have misread the exercise, because the condition only holds for $n=1$.

Comment: I do not feel that only $n=1$ works. In case i), $24\mod 7 = 3$. Similarly, in ii) $20 \mod 6 = 2$ I have only changed the exercise to have the existential quantifier for $x,y$ to be $\forall$; whereas the exercise wanted to ask conditions on all the three numbers, i.e. $x,y,z$. This exercise is from page #26, question no. 2.3.5 of the book : Approximately Calculus, by Shahriar Shahriari.

Comment: Changing $\exists$ into $\forall$ makes for a completely different problem.

Comment: As stated, the answer is clearly $n=1$.  If $n>1$ then $n$ does not divide $1\times 0 -1$ so taking $x=1,y=0$ would give an immediate counterexample.  As has been pointed out, changing the quantifiers will most likely change the answer.

Comment: So, for $\forall$ quantifier, $n=1$ is the solution. I am sorry for not understanding the gravity of the quantifiers in this situation. Is there possible to have any answer for the $\exists$ case.

Comment: I think you can come up with examples where this holds.  (Hint:  choose $y$ to make $xy=x$ as integers).

Comment: $y=an+1$ with $a\in Z$.

Comment: @tp1 But your formula fails in the second case.

Comment: It seems an arithmetic expression can be formed that must involve all the three quantities, not just two. May be as @lulu said, it is all case-wise construction of such examples. Not clear on the first approach, and definitely not feasible to construct such examples too many by the latter approach.

Comment: Will $l.(xy) \pm k.(xn)  \equiv 0\pmod n, \exists k,n \in \mathbb {Z}$ work? For the second case, $l = 3, k = 1$, works as $l.(xy) = 60$, and $k.(xn) = 12$.

Comment: You are overcomplicating this. just take $y=1$.  Then your equation holds for all $x,n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming arbitrary $n > 0$ there are two solutions here that always hold, and any solution is a member of these two families. The first is $x = 0$ which is trivial. Otherwise we're looking for solutions:

$$xy \equiv x \mod n \iff x(y - 1) \equiv 0 \mod n$$

Thus after choosing arbitrary $x$ we can choose any $y$ such that $x(y-1) = kn$. Or $y = \frac{kn}{x} + 1$, whenever that expression is integer for integer $k$.

Thus for highly composite $n$ we can get many solutions for $y$. E.g. for $n = 60$ and $x = 30$ we find that permissible $y$ are:

$$1, 3, 5, 7, \dots, 57, 59$$

Comment: Nice, insightful, easy. Thanks a lot.